# How to add electron in electron-builder built exe

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, asar

I am trying to build an exe for an electron application. Using `electron-builder 24.9.1` and `electron 28.1.2`. The electron module is missing from the built application. To make sure that is the problem I installed the built exe then went to the installation location and from there extracted `app.asar` in that there was `node_modules` but no electron in it.

[image: electron not found]

I tried unpacking the asar file and added electron manually then packed it again. After all this kept the file where the installation location was. Booh yeah! the application worked fine.